# Can anyone explain how this scrambling function works?

Tags: php

I'm working with a function taken from [Corrupt](https://github.com/recyclism/Corrupt) (a web based piece of software used to get "glitchy" effects using jpeg images). This function can be found in the [corrupt.php](https://github.com/recyclism/Corrupt/blob/master/corrupt.php) file on line 23. At the moment it's not making the files glitchy enough. I made [this images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYlCK.jpg) to show you how I want the images to look. This was made by opening the jpeg in a text editor and cutting certain lines and pasting them in other places.

I want this function to do a similar thing but at the moment it doesn't. Any ideas? Is there a better way of doing this maybe?

```
function scramble($content, $size) {
    $sStart = 10;
    $sEnd = $size-1;
    $nReplacements = rand(1, 30);

    for($i = 0; $i < $nReplacements; $i++) {
        $PosA = rand($sStart, $sEnd);
        $PosB = rand($sStart, $sEnd);

        $tmp = $content[$PosA];
        $content[$PosA] = $content[$PosB];
        $content[$PosB] = $tmp;
    }

    return($content);
}
```

Comment: note that this is a very naive way of altering the contents of the file and is probably going to result in completely unusable (truly corrupted) files. It would probably be safer to open the file as a GD image and make changes on the pixel data. The jpeg file format has many types of blocks and most of them are of variable block sizes. You twiddle the wrong bits and you have corrupted the headers, not the image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is randomly swapping information around in the data arrays loaded from your image. This causes a valid image to come out with invalid image information in some sectors. Also, image files sometimes contain additional information at the front/end of the file; this does not look like it takes that into account and could corrupt that information as well.

To increase the amount of swaps you will want to increase the number of replacements. The bit of code you are particularly interested in is `rand(1, 30);`; I would suggest increasing the minimum amount of scramble first and then the upper range if you still do not get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

The function does random swaps between the elements of the array. The number of swaps is a randomly generated number from 1 to 30.